# FFmpeg multiple drawtext filters next to each other

Tags: animation, ffmpeg, drawtext, video-subtitles

I would like to draw text on a video with ffmpeg that

- has multiple lines
- some of the words in these lines are in bold text style while others are not
- the lines need to be animated with the timeline option

What options do I have here? I know that when it comes to make some words bold within a line, I would better go with the subtitle filter. But as far as I know, I cannot animate subtitles, right?

That is why I am wondering whether I could use multiple drawtext filters next to each other. But how can I pass on the information of the width of one drawtext to the next one in order for it to match the correct coordinates?

Comment: "Animate" can mean so many different things. Can you explain exactly what you need the text to do?

Comment: @llogan: Of course, sorry! What I meant: Move from point A to B in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter with ASS subtitles. The subtitles can be moved using the [`\move` override tag](https://aegi.vmoe.info/docs/3.0/ASS_Tags/#index29h3):

[image]

Example ASS file:

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,48,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,2,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\move(0,-10,320,350,0,2000)}Moving {\b1}text{\b0}{\move}
```